# calculate sampling error given dispersion and probability

Tags: statistics, sampling

A professor is estimating avg number of hours any student needs to pass his stat course.

the dispersion is 2.6, With probability 90% calculate number of hours needed for research if the sample error should not exceed 5%.

I have no idea how to solve problems like that, steer me in the right direction?

Comment: What does *dispersion* mean here? Do you have any information about the location of the distribution?

Comment: @Henry, the question is stated as it is. just calculate things.. i never seen questions like this before